# Get MysQL rows where 2 words match

Tags: search, mysql, many-to-many

I am trying to build an easy search based on 2 `MySQL` tables. One called keywords (words) and another called keyword2data (map which binds words to datasource).

Keywords holds id and keyword whilst keywords2data holds keyword_id and data_id.

data_id it self is a reference to a 3rd but in this case unimportant table.

What i want is to be able to search for example "dog sled" and get all data_id's which has those keywords bound to it.

```
SELECT k2d.`data_id` , k2d.`keyword_id` 
FROM keywords2data as k2d, keywords as k 
WHERE k2d.`keyword_id` = k.`id` 
&& (k.`keyword` = 'dog' || k.`keyword` = 'sled') 
LIMIT 10
```

Gives me all data_id which has either dog or sled bound to it, not necessary both, which is what i want.

```
SELECT k2d.`data_id` , k2d.`keyword_id` 
FROM keywords2data as k2d, keywords as k 
WHERE k2d.`keyword_id` = k.`id` 
&& (k.`keyword` = 'dog' && k.`keyword` = 'sled') 
LIMIT 10
```

Gives me nothing since no single row in keywords2data holds 2 keywords.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: As I explain in my question, neither or my examples work. One gives me too many results and one gives me none. I want results only where both dog and sled exists. And no, using AND didn't work as I explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT k2d.`data_id`, 
       k2d.`keyword_id` 
FROM   keywords2data AS k2d 
       INNER JOIN keywords AS k 
         ON k2d.`keyword_id` = k.`id` 
WHERE  k.`keyword` IN ( 'dog', 'sled', 'rex' ) 
GROUP  BY k.keyword 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: This is not bad, only 1 JOIN for all the keywords you need, as long as k.keyword has a unique index.

Comment: Looks promising. Going to give this a try and yes, keyword is unique and only exists once with an unique id.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` fetches nothing. Removing it fetches 3 rows, each with same id. Changing it to `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` gives same result as removing it. I guess this is because it actually only fetches one unique data_id. Having `GROUP BY k2d.`data_id`` seems to work better and only fetches 1 row, if there is only containing these words :) Thanks!

Comment: Hum.. seems like that wasn't a good solution either. Went back on testing your original solution. While testing, with 3 keywords i know exist on 2 pages, that have identical text, i only fetch 1 of them. Why? If i remove just ´HAVING COUNT(*) = 3´ I get all pages having these 3 keywords. I get 3 rows back, 2 pages having both keywords and 1 page only having the first. This do work, but it is not optimal.

Comment: Okey, back from more testing. :P Found out another problem. If I now try and search for only the first word, which I know exist on 2 pages i only get one row. Weird?

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
SELECT  k2d.`data_id` , 
        k2d.`keyword_id`  
FROM    keywords2data as k2d INNER JOIN
        keywords as k  ON k2d.`keyword_id` = k.`id` INNER JOIN
        keywords as k2  ON k2d.`keyword_id` = k2.`id`
WHERE   k.`keyword` = 'dog' 
AND     k2.`keyword` = 'sled'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This works for two keywords, but what if the number of keywords is variable? Do we need one join per keyword?

Comment: yeah, there could be 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6... keywords. But perhaps this is the only way?

Comment: I actually can't get this to work. I get no result. :S And, yes, I know for example in this case that there is 2 rows with data_id 29 that has keyword_id for dog and sled.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, this?

To extend to match more keywords you'd just add more words to the `OR` statement in the subquery and change the `=2` afterwards.

This assumes that each data item is linked to a keyword using `kerywords2data` once and only once.

```
SELECT k2d.data_id
     , k2d.keyword_id

FROM keywords2data AS k2d
   , keywords AS k 

WHERE k2d.keyword_id = k.id
  AND (
       SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM keywords2data AS sqk2d
           , keywords AS sqk 
        WHERE sqk2d.data_id = k2d.data_id
          AND sqk2d.keyword_id = sqk.id
          AND (sqk.keyword = 'dog' || sqk.keyword = 'sled')
       ) = 2

LIMIT 10
```

Here's a version that doesn't return the `data_id` repeated (as per comments), but also doesn't return any keywords at all:

```
SELECT k2d.data_id

FROM keywords2data AS k2d

WHERE (
       SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM keywords2data AS sqk2d
            , keywords AS sqk 
        WHERE sqk2d.data_id = k2d.data_id
          AND sqk2d.keyword_id = sqk.id
          AND (sqk.keyword = 'dog' || sqk.keyword = 'sled')
      ) = 2

LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @jamie Ah, good point, if you just need the `data_id` back of anything that matches all the tags just remove *all* references to `k` from the parent query - I'll update my answer with an example.